# Deleting/moving folders created in tar installation

Tags: software-installation, tar

If you install `namepackage.tar.bz2` (or any other extension of tar) when being in the folder `home/name/Downloads` (meaning installing through terminal in that directory), can you delete the folder `namepackage` that was created in the installation? If not, can you move it somewhere else?

I think it's a basic question but couldn't find an answer online.

My operating system is Debian 8 specifically but doubt that makes any difference for my question.

Comment: If your referring to the `.deb` file that was used in the install, then yes you can delete it.

Comment: Did you mean when you install a program from source ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re referring to the typical installation scenario using a source tarball, *i.e.*

```
tar xf namepackage.tar.bz2
cd namepackage
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

then yes, you can delete the `namepackage` directory afterwards, the installed software doesn’t need it.

Keep the original tarball around if you can, it might come in handy in the future (and when you realise you need it, it might no longer be available online).